# If $a^2+b^2+c^2 =3$, find the minimum value of $a+b+c$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality, qclp

Given that their are 3 positive real numbers $a,b,c$, such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, find the minimum value of $a+b+c$

Comment: Try using the concept of Lagrange multipliers... it will make the question extremely easy.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know calculus, isn't their any other way for solving this inequality ??

Comment: Are you sure the minimum exists?  I'd have said $(\sqrt 3,0,0)$ (or it's permutations) was the minimum but it is  not in your allowed domain, though you can approach it by taking two very small positive values instead of the zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)$ seeking the minimum in nonnegative variables you minimize $(ab+bc+ac)$ for it is zero having two null variables example $a=b=0.$
Finally the minimum is $a+b+c=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: The problem says that all of them are positive variables. You have claimed that their are 2 null variables. Please clarify

Comment: As lulu said it is a general answer, the minimum for positive $a,b,c$ $>0$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Actually, this question was inspired from this problem - https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2032845_inequality

Comment: I came up to this so I asked for help. If you could help me with the solution for it, please post it.

Comment: ok you divided the required inequality in two, a common mistake...